# What is the difference between REFERENCES with, or without a FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database, android-sqlite, ddl

In regards to `SQLite`, What is the difference between REFERENCES with, or without a FOREIGN KEY?

What is the difference between this

```
CREATE TABLE players_set ( 
    _id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                           NOT NULL,
    player_id      INTEGER REFERENCES players ( _id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    players_set_id INTEGER REFERENCES players_set_names ( _id ) 
);
```

and this:

```
CREATE TABLE players_set ( 
    _id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                           NOT NULL,
    player_id INTEGER,
    players_set_id INTEGER REFERENCES players_set_names ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players ( _id ) ON DELETE CASCADE        
);
```

I found  this other question:
[Difference between using REFERENCES with and without FOREIGN KEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230892/difference-between-using-references-with-and-without-foreign-key)

I read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), it didn't make it clear for me though.

To be precise, I'm using SQLite on `Android` (hence the tag). I don't know if that makes any difference, but if it has its own quirks, it would be very useful for me to find out about.

Comment: If you ever have to use MySQL, don't use the first version: MySQL will ignore the foreign key definition (i.e. it will not be created) but will not tell you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name or don't use mysql ;)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: I couldn't agree more ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FOREIGN KEY` syntax is more flexible than defining it inline in the column definition (e.g., it allows you to define a composite foreign key, where the combination of two or more fields should exist in the referencing columns).

In your case, there is no difference between the two DDL statements. One could say that the inline definition of foreign keys is nothing more than syntactic sugaring.