# Does REFERENCES have to be always used together with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

The table Friendship only uses REFERENCES without FOREIGN KEY keyword. Is it a mistake without coupling with Foreign Key keyword, or is it valid and represents another semantics? The Friendship table is supposed to hold IDs of any pair of two friends.

```
Create table Student (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Create table Book (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
  REFERENCES Student(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Create table Friendship (
  id_from int NOT NULL REFERENCES Student(id),
  id_to int NOT NULL REFERENCES Student(id), 
  PRIMARY KEY (id_from, id_to) 
);
```

I created the 3 tables in MySql and inserted some data into them, and I am able to do searches like "find all friends of "John" correctly.

But I am not very sure whether REFERENCES can be used alone like this as a foreign key constraint.

Edited:

Follow the comment's suggestion, I modified the Friendship to the following:

```
Create table Friendship (
  id_from int NOT NULL,
  id_to int NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id_from, id_to)
  FOREIGN KEY (id_from) REFERENCES Student(id)
  FOREIGN KEY (id_to) REFERENCES Student(id)
);
```

But now I received a syntax error in creating this table:

```
Create table Friendship (
    ->   id_from int NOT NULL,
    ->   id_to int NOT NULL, 
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id_from, id_to)
    ->   FOREIGN KEY (id_from) REFERENCES Student(id)
    ->   FOREIGN KEY (id_to) REFERENCES Student(id)
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (id_from) REFERENCES Student(id)
  FOREIGN KEY (id_to) REFERENCES Student(' at line 5
```

Comment: Read before with question-answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14230934/2253302

Comment: Does this mean that I have to add "FOREIGN KEY" to the Friendship table creation statement? If that is the case, why does the current code work well when I test them on MySql?

Comment: Of course, you can search even without foreign keys or references. But there are some constraints, for example Update and Delete Anomalies

Comment: If I add ""FOREIGN KEY" keyword to Friendship, then "id_from" and "id_to" would be both primary key and foreign key. Can a key be both at the same time?

Comment: @alexander.polomodov, please see my updated version and the error message.

Comment: You forgot commas between pk, and fk
`Create table Friendship (
  id_from int NOT NULL,
  id_to int NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id_from, id_to),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_from) REFERENCES Student(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_to) REFERENCES Student(id)
);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105412/discussion-between-user697911-and-alexander-polomodov).